# passing model to action method in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, actionmethod

I have a view which look like this

```
    @model UI.Models.BidOnAuctionViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{
    var disableButton = Model.AuctionOpen ? "" : "bid-btn-disabled";         
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmBid", "Lot"))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuctionId)

        <p>
            <label >&pound;@Model.NextBidAmount</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            @if (Model.AuctionOpen)
            {
                 <input type="submit" value="Place bid" class="bid-btn @disableButton" />
            }
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I click on the Place bid button, I go to the confirmBid action method

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmBid(BidOnAuctionViewModel model)
```

The problem is that even though in the view the model was not null, for some reason it is null in this action method.  Why is this?

Comment: Why you are passing the model in Form? It automatically gets the current model when you post because you have already specified type for view.

Comment: Ok but I tried not to pass the form and although the model wasn't null, certain fields in the model which should have not been null were.

Comment: Do you mean to say some of the fields are null not the whole model?

Comment: yes some fields are null when I don't pass the model like I just showed

Comment: Some fields become null because you didn't specified anything in to that fields in view.

Comment: but the model that came into that view does contain values for those fields

Comment: okay than provide your whole view mark up. Might be there are some duplicate name fields

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean null I meant 0.  The value is a decimal and it is 0 not null

Comment: Just paste you whole view code

Comment: Done - the value that is 0 is NextBidAmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing your code i found the issue. Actually you are just displaying the value of `NextBidAmount`. And when form get post again the model object lost its value.

To persist its value on post in model just create a hidden field for it as you already done for `AuctionId`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NextBidAmount)
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Why does this happen.  Why do you need to put a hidden field in?

Comment: Hidden field persist the value of you field on post. Form will post all the input fields to controller and you were not putting it in to any input element.